# accessing ofbiz application that is installed on windows server virtually in azure

Tags: deployment, ofbiz

I have created windows server VM and installed ofbiz framework with Demo data. The framework is working fine when accessed through VM itself, but I need a way to access it outside (through local browsers).

Answer (score 3):

You need to open ports (8080 and 8443) to access it from outside the azure VM. Here you go on how to do that- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/setup-endpoints?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Fclassic%2Ftoc.json

You can also use the Apache OFBiz Mailing list for such queries - https://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

HTH!